# Create a file in the sdcard

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to create a new file from a class that not implements an Activity. If I use the same code on a class that implements an activity the file is created but not if the class doesnt implement an activity. Whats wrong? Should I need the context? How can I do?

```
public class fileInfo {
File filename;
int indexfile;

public filesInfo(){
    indexfile = 0;

    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/MotionSensors/values.txt";
    filename = new File(filepath);

}
```

}
            ..
            }

Comment: That should work... btw please fix your syntax error in your example.

Comment: You need to post real, executable examples and explain your problem with enough detail that we can see what you are doing wrong. Otherwise how are we supposed to be able to help you?

Comment: have you tried as `filename = new File(filepath); boolean result = filename.createNewFile();`

Comment: Note that the subfolder must exist before you try to create a file.  Creating the file by including a subfolder in it's path will not also create the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done above looks alright, but still if it doesn't work, then try this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This will create a file from non-activity class.

Comment: What's the path? if I put the filepath it doesnt works, if not I dont know the location where the file is created.

Comment: @skiria : you have add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in manifast.xml ?

Comment: @skiria : also try filename = new File(filepath); boolean result = filename.createNewFile(); code for creating file

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake... It forgot to add external permission.

Comment: @skiria : not silly mistake this is very big mistake because without permission nothing worked. so always first add permission in manifast before requesting for any service from system